# "We choose our partners by..."

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, business-language

I want to say that we (as a company) choose only the best companies to join our partners program and I'm looking for a better way to say it.

Something like:

> We choose our partners by _____.

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We choose our partners with [**discernment**](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/1417828)

We choose our partners discernedly

> Discernment is a term used to describe the activity of determining the
>   value and quality of a certain subject or event. Typically, it is used
>   to describe the activity of going past the mere perception of
>   something, to making detailed judgments about that thing. As a virtue,
>   a discerning individual is considered to possess wisdom, and be of
>   good judgement; especially so with regard to subject matter often
>   overlooked by others.

Answer (score 1):

We choose our partners on **merit**.

Answer (score 1):

Consider simply saying:

> We choose our partners *by ourselves*.